# VCR cassette Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, amazon-kms, vcr

My product keys are encrypted using aws kms.

Can I create a cassette with my credentials for *aws* and then use same answer for other credentials?

To encrypt key, I send a `plaintext` to *kms*, `ciphertextblob` comes in response.
For decryption, on contrary, I send `ciphertextblob`.

I need a specific answer to come with other credentials in `secrets.yml`. With given `plaintext` and `ciphertextblob`.

Is it possible?

My encrypt cassette:

```
---
http_interactions:
- request:
    method: post
    uri: https://kms.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
    body:
      encoding: UTF-8
      string: '{"KeyId":"c503e...","Plaintext":"c29tZV9zZWNyZXRfa2V5"}'
    headers:
      Content-Type:
      - application/x-amz-json-1.1
      Accept-Encoding:
      - ''
      User-Agent:
      - aws-sdk-ruby2/2.11.350 ruby/2.6.5 x86_64-darwin16
      X-Amz-Target:
      - TrentService.Encrypt
      X-Amz-Date:
      - 20191027T114350Z
      Host:
      - kms.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
      X-Amz-Content-Sha256:
      - e44f3b42ea47f0da15d3ea308f0fe18f...
      Authorization:
      - AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIA.../20191027/us-east-1/kms/aws4_request,
        SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-target,
        Signature=6734f877ffaab94...
      Content-Length:
      - '83'
      Accept:
      - "*/*"
  response:
    status:
      code: 200
      message: OK
    headers:
      X-Amzn-Requestid:
      - ab60...
      Cache-Control:
      - no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
      Expires:
      - '0'
      Pragma:
      - no-cache
      Date:
      - Sun, 27 Oct 2019 11:43:50 GMT
      Content-Type:
      - application/x-amz-json-1.1
      Content-Length:
      - '331'
    body:
      encoding: UTF-8
      string: '{"CiphertextBlob":"AQICAHhJfqHORt4q1tArVIjeOnn8HhbsQrVfjk1RwvzFcQ0PBwEQePP62gO7cgVCj1QBPiVEAAAAbTBrBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagXjBcAgEAMFcGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMtE/2tUMFssj2rYo+AgEQgCpF8oeItgXSUf/Xm17vEdTjScA7s+u21tLCPYb/WrTf+OZnZCp/wzgA7k8=","KeyId":"arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:9300...:key/c503..."}'
    http_version: 
  recorded_at: Sun, 27 Oct 2019 11:43:50 GMT
recorded_with: VCR 5.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [filter sensitive data](https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/3-0-1/docs/configuration/filter-sensitive-data) in VCR. Store your credentials per environment in the `ENV` via something like [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv), and filter out the `ENV` value. e.g.

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.filter_sensitive_data('<<AWS_CREDENTIALS>>') { ENV['AWS_CREDENTIALS'] }
end
```